# Disable overflow-y if modal-dialog pops up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this CSS property in my app because it fixes a lot of scrollbars within my app to do with wrong scroll placement.

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Because I'm applying it to html and I'm within the modal-dialog I scroll the body of my app if there's no scrollbar on the modal. How do I modify that css property to work everywhere except on the modal-dialogs?

It's working fine if there's scrollbar within the modal-dialog because it uses the right one but when there isn't one I'm just scrolling the background of it.

I've tried example below (from one of the existing threads) but it doesn't cover my scenario when I use the above css too.

```
.modal-dialog{
    overflow-y: initial !important
}
.modal-body{
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: You could try to remove `overflow-y: scroll;` on the `html` element on **modal open** ... then on **modal close** add `overflow-y: scroll;` again

Comment: Well in theory that's what my question is about, how to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using frameworks such a Bootstrap, then you can use the [Modal Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events) to make it work as how you want. I have used a combination of jQuery and CSS to achieve this in Bootstrap 2, which doesn't always remove the scrollbars of `body`, when a modal is open.

```
$('#modal-id').on('hidden', function () {
    $("body").removeClass("model-open");
}).on('show', function () {
    $("body").addClass("model-open");
});
```

I have used above two events, on `hidden` and on `show`. And I am also adding the class to the `body`, in your case, it would be `html`.

```css
.model-open {overflow: hidden;}
```

Hope this gives you a starting point. `:)`

Comment: I have tried adding overflow:hidden to modal-dialog or modal-body and that didn't change what the html { overflow-y: scroll; } does

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk Which version of Bootstrap are you using and can you please give more context on your question please?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.7

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk Then the hiding of scrollbars will happen automatically. You wanna create a [**JSBin**](https://jsbin.com) with your existing code and show what's happening and what you expect to happen, please? That will be more helpful to help you debug the issue.

Comment: There isn't much to add to the code. I'm using html { overflow-y: scroll; } in my layout.css and trying to add .modal-dialog { overflow-y: hidden; }  OR  .modal-body { overflow-y: hidden; } but nothing works. I can scroll the page even though modal is on the screen.

Comment: Dude, can you make a snippet or fiddle please? It's not like you think, or at least for me, who can fix this in an instant, it's hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

## Using bootstrap events

Remove `overflow-y: scroll;` on the `html` element on **modal open** ... then on **modal close** add
 `overflow-y: scroll;` again

```
$('#modalSelector').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('html').css("overflow-y", "");
})

$('#modalSelector').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('html').css("overflow-y", "scroll");
})
```